# how to read the desired page using document.getelement

Tags: javascript

This is my code in javascript to parse a document but I want it to parse the document on the given url and not the one I'm coding on.

I am using `location.href` to redirect it to the desired url but its not working and the current url displayed is of my web from (the one I'm working on)

```
<script  type="text/javascript" >
    function wordcount () {
       //location.href='http://www.w3schools.com';
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
        alert(window.location.toString().toLowerCase());
        var words = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML.replace(/<.*?>/g,'');
        alert( words.match(/\S+/g));
        //alert("hi");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You mean you need to get the html of the w3schools.com?

Comment: yes but the problem is it isnt...why isnt redirecting to the new page and reading the old page instead.

Comment: You need to look into cross domain ajax request. Refer [this](http://hayageek.com/cross-domain-ajax-request-jquery/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about/2067584#2067584)

Comment: im not familier with JSONP and jquery...can you please point the problem in this.

Comment: or suggest another way in java script/asp.net

Comment: none of these are working even for a local file such as Webform2.aspx

Comment: location.href='http://www.w3schools.com';
            window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
             return false;
            window.location.replace("../WebForm2.aspx");
           self.location.href="http://www.google.com";

Comment: please help people im pulling my hair out here.